# Is the [multitouch] tag needed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

Tag [multi-touch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-touch) is useless because these years almost all devices support multi touch, and we have other tags such as [touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchpad) or [touchscreen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchscreen) that is used for every question with the [multi-touch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-touch) tag.

Also, only five questions with this tag has been created this year and none of them is exactly meaning multi touch, but instead they are about other touch devices which have multi-touch functionality for sure, so no question needs this tag to say something about the question.

Also, we can add the one-touch tag or no-multi-touch tag, because one-touch devices are rarer than multi-touch devices.

Comment: And if it is a question about a device that freaks out when multiple touches are recognized or not recognized? What then?

Comment: @SeanAllred we can add opposite tag because of usage. question edited

Comment: @SeanAllred There is no requirement to have a specific tag for every single kind of problem. In fact, that's exactly *not* what we want.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Of course not; that would be absolutely useless. Tags are supposed to be general categories of problems, and I think it's incredibly presumptuous to think that "these years all devices support multi-touch".  Maybe that's just me and my exposure though.

Comment: @SeanAllred That's a valid point and I would agree that not every touch device supports multi-touch. But the distinction shouldn't be important enough to require a specific tag.

Comment: I think the multitouch tag should only be used to specify problems with the multitouch feature specifically.

Comment: @VirtualDXS As Oliver pointed out, it's sufficient for the question to mention that it's an issue with multitouch in the title or body. IMO it's not really a distinct enough category to warrant another tag in addition to [tag:touch*], nor would it be particularly useful for filtering (one of the main purposes of tags).

Comment: Good question admin. Nicely explained.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg The tag is **gone now!**

Answer (score 3):

Potentially, yes.  For example, "How can I disable pinch-to-zoom on the Windows 7 desktop?" would be a valid `multi-touch` sort of a question.  And look, the tag actually is used validly on several questions:

- [How can I get Pinch to Zoom back in Desktop mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/499011/how-can-i-get-pinch-to-zoom-back-in-desktop-mode)
- [Does RDP support Multitouch? (and if not, does anything?)](https://superuser.com/questions/250565/does-rdp-support-multitouch-and-if-not-does-anything)
- [Can I send multitouch gestures over VNC to OS X Lion?](https://superuser.com/q/341188/29943)

If you see it abused, remove it from questions where it isn't helpful.  But that doesn't mean the whole tag should go.

Comment: So, the consensus was to keep this tag... and it's gone?